# Query Object Pattern vs LINQ

Tags: linq, design-patterns

I am busy with a new project and am working on my repository layer.  This will be my 2nd project using the Repository Pattern. I have been reading Scott Millett's book *Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns*  In referencing the case study in the book, Scott has used the Query Object Pattern in in his repository interfaces.  In my previous project I used LINQ for this purpose and it worked well.

My question is as follows: **What are the pros and cons of using a Query Object Pattern implementation versus using LINQ in your repository?**

Here are 2 scenarios which illustrate the 2 different approaches:

**1. Query Object Pattern approach**

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T, TId> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    T FindBy(TId id);
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
    IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Query query);
}
```

**2. LINQ approach**

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T, TId> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    T FindBy(TId id);
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query);
}
```

Any contributions would be helpful.

Comment: IMHO, expression trees are a special form of the query object pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think the expression trees of LINQ are just a special form of the query object pattern, because of their greater flexibility, they allow you to introduce bugs in your code that only are visible at runtime.
I am talking about C# code that gets successfully converted to an expression tree, but is not understood by the provider that is supposed to translate it to SQL.

Example:

```
var a = new SpecialObject();
yourRepository.FindBy(x => a.IsCorrect(x));
```

An error like this would be impossible with an ordinary query object.

Comment: So Daniel, to confirm my understanding, am I correct in that are you saying that the flexible nature of LINQ can result in scenarios where code compile, but it is actually not valid?

Comment: Yes, most definitely! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920775/why-would-entity-framework-not-be-able-to-use-tostring-in-a-linq-statement) for one of many examples.

Comment: Or just [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method+%27%2A%27+method%2C+and+this+method+cannot+be+translated+into+a+store+expression.%22&oq=%22LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method+%27*%27+method%2C+and+this+method+cannot+be+translated+into+a+store+expression.%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3041l3041l0l5273l1l1l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0) the exception message that occurs in a case like this.