# EF - linq2entities does not recognize .tostring() method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm unable to compile the below code and I'm getting the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()
```

I'm a bit surprised because I was able to do this in Linq2SQL but can't do it in Entity Framework.

Could I please get any help rewriting the below code ? I've seen a few examples related to this error but I couldn't find something that is specific to this scenario. Thanks

```
 using (ctx)
 {
                   var productResults = (from q in ctx.Products
                                         where q.ProductId == productId && q.Model == productModel
                                         select new Models.ProductDTO
                                         {
                                             Id = q.ProductId,
                                             Name = q.Name.ToString(),
                                             Year = q.Year.ToString("MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"),
                                             Model = q.Model,
                                             Description = q.Description.ToString()
                                         }).Distinct().ToList().AsParallel();
                   Department.Products = productResults;
                }
```

Comment: If Description is of type string already, why would you need to call ToString() on it?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, May be he does not need for Name and Description, But He needs for date to string... `(q.Year.ToString("MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would Entity Framework not be able to use ToString() in a LINQ statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920775/why-would-entity-framework-not-be-able-to-use-tostring-in-a-linq-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get list from `context`

```
var productResults = ctx.Products.where(q => q.ProductId == productId && q.Model == productModel).ToList();
```

Then query is and select new Type as `ProductDTO`

```
var productDTO = (from q in productResults 
                 select new Models.ProductDTO
                 {
                      Id = q.ProductId,
                      Name = q.Name.ToString(),
                      Year = q.Year.ToString("MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"),
                      Model = q.Model,
                      Description = q.Description.ToString()
                 }).Distinct().ToList().AsParallel();
```

**AFTER COMMENT**

IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Products> list = context.Products.Take(10);
// after this line data load the memory that fetched from DB.
```

SQL Output:

```
 Select * FROM Table
```

IQuerable:

```
IQuerable<Products> list = context.Products.Take(10);
// data still not fetch from DB
```

SQL Output:

```
 Select Top 10 FROM Table
```

Comment: It works..Thanks a lot..!!.If possible, please see my other question in the answer below, and let me know what you think. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may also do this in one query;

```
            var productResults = ctx.Products.Where(q => q.ProductId == productId && q.Model == productModel).ToList()
                .Select<Product, ProductDTO>(m =>
                {
                    Models.ProductDTO dto= new Models.ProductDTO();
                    dto.Id = m.ProductId;
                    dto.Name = m.Name.ToString();
                    dto.Year = m.Year.ToString("MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy");
                    dto.Model = m.Model;
                    dto.Description = m.Description.ToString();
                    return dto;
                }).Distinct().ToList().AsParallel();
```

there may be a better way, but breaking it into two queries may work.

```
var productResults = (from q in ctx.Products
     where q.ProductId == productId && q.Model == productModel
     select q).ToList();

var temp = from o in productResults
         select new Models.ProductDTO
         {
             Id = q.ProductId,
             Name = q.Name.ToString(),
             Year = q.Year.ToString("MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"),
             Model = q.Model,
             Description = q.Description.ToString()
         }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: the trick here is calling to list after first query; then it works exactly in the same way any Linq query works since the data is fetched to memory.

Comment: Better is to use `.AsEnumerable()` instead of your first `.ToList()`: there is no point in saving all `Product`s in a list if you're going to discard that list. The only use `.ToList()` has is to force `.Select()` to resolve to `Enumerable.Select` instead of `Queryable.Select`, and `.AsEnumerable()` achieves that same result.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.!!.I'm only a beginner, and got one more question. I tried both your way and AliRiza's(answer above) way of creating the list. Both work perfectly but which one is better ? is there any difference ? Which is the good practice ? - Thanks

Comment: @user1980311, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi this link does not seem to directly related; in both answers using ToList call, both is converted to IEnumerable. I see no direct performance difference between both answers (may be Jon Skeet may have an answer).

Comment: So, If I have a view Model such as 'public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }', Is it better to change it to public IQueryable<ProductDTO> ?, will it still work if I change .ToList to .AsQueryable() ?

Comment: @user1980311 calling ToList results in the query to run in the database; you may refer to the question provided in one of the comments (or you may google for it as "deferred execution" etc. You may change ToList to AsEnumerable which will result a slight performance increase.

Comment: A more layman explanation on why you had the problem is that EF tries to translate the expression in the select clause to SQL. It doesn't know how to convert the `ToString()` method into SQL. By using `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()`, the latter being the better option, you stop using EF and start using actual functions (executable code), at which point the `ToString()` method will no longer be interpreted, but instead will be invoked. If you want to minimize the data being pulled over the network (and into memory), select into an anonymous type, then use that type to fill your DTO.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help..!!..I will start looking into deferred execution now..