# Entity Framework ToString method

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Following code block throws error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
db.tbOnIgmHawbDetails
  .Where(s => !db.tbImpoExaminations.Any(x => x.Hawb.ToString() == s.Hawb) && s.AwbNo == p)
  .Select(s => s.Hawb).ToList();
```

Any suggestion? why this happen and what is the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Comment: Why are you comparing the tostring representations of the variable why not just `x.hawb == s.hawb`?

Comment: x.hawb is type of long, and x.hawb is type of string, so....

Comment: I think you should override ToString function, for example, define new function named 'HawbToString' for Type of object of x. ok?

Comment: You have tagged Linq-To-Sql but you get a Linq-To-Entities excption?

Comment: @DanDrews There aren't good solutions in the suggested duplicates. They all suggest to make it a LINQ-To-Objects. Here it's not possible

Comment: You dont have any navigation properties? This is wrong way to use EF, you are supposed to create proper FK relations and use navigation properties to query them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would Entity Framework not be able to use ToString() in a LINQ statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920775/why-would-entity-framework-not-be-able-to-use-tostring-in-a-linq-statement)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try with `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`... Use the `decimal` conversion:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)p.x.Hawb).TrimLeft() == ...
```

(the `TrimLeft` is necessary because the `STR` function of SQL will right align the number)

Comment: ToString() is supported with EF 6.1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Answer (score 15):

`.ToString()` is supported properly going forward with EF 6.1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Comment: Good news :-) Thanks for mentioning that information here

Comment: This works, and it helped improve performance of operations that were using .AsEnumerable()

Answer (score 1):

If `s.Hawb` is already string type (the error message suggests so), then remove the part `.ToString()` from your query.

The reason for it is that in LINQ2SQL, you can only use those language constructs that can be translated into SQL. For example, if you try to use RegEx in your C# expression, then SQL does not have a corresponding construct for RegEx, and thus LINQ cannot translate and execute your query.

Comment: -1 - how can you call `s.Hawb.ToString()` *outside* of LINQ query when `s` is part of lambda query?

Answer (score 1):

Easily add `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.ToString()` and those methods that L2E doesn't support:

```
var asen = db.tbOnIgmHawbDetails.AsEnumerable();

var result =  asen.Where(s => !asen.Any(x => x.Hawb.ToString() == s.Hawb) && s.AwbNo == p)
  .Select(s => s.Hawb).ToList();
```

That should works. However if not, try to perform your query by linq-to-objects syntax:

```
var result = from a in asen
             where ...
             select ...;
```

Comment: Won't `AsEnumerable()` cause the next call to run the query? That will pull down the entire table which defeats the point of using a database to begin with...

Comment: @StevenHunt of course it does! L2E only translate your L2E command to raw sql so it doesn't recognize `.ToString()` or any other function... You should pull desired records from db and perform such functions to the in-memory list... it's just one of several ways to achieve that goal...

Answer (score 0):

do not use ToString

just use like

**`x.Hawb + "" == s.Hawb`**