# How to fix "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime GetValueOrDefault()'"?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I  have this code. Basically i need to change the date and tell user that today, the store will be open from 10 am to 10 pm. So the time here is fixed.

**from:-**

today_date = "2020-03-23T00:00:00"

start_hour_time = "1900-01-01T10:00:00"

end_hour_time = "1900-01-01T22:00:00"

**change to :-**

start_newdatetime =  "2020-03-23T10:00:00"

end_newdatetime = "2020-03-23T22:00:00"

```
DateTime todaysdate = DateTime.Now.Date;       

var find_date = bdb.tbl_store
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.start_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.a.end_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Where(x => x.a.a.store_id == store_id )
        .Select(x => new {

        x.a.a.store_id,
        start_hour_time = x.a.b.hour_time,
        end_hour_time = x.b.hour_time,
        start_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date+ x.a.b.hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay,
        end_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date + x.b.hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay

    }) .ToList();
```

the problem now, it is error. Because i want it to be on the same var.

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",  "ExceptionMessage": "LINQ to
>   Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   GetValueOrDefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.",  "ExceptionType":
>   "System.NotSupportedException",

but it will be okey if i create another var to return the new value.

Comment: Judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684466/3181933), it looks like you should be able to use `(x.a.b.hour_time ?? TimeSpan.Zero)`.

Comment: I have tried it from that answer, it does not work. I cannot simply add ?? after the x.a.b.hour_time as it will return error.

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime?' and 'TimeSpan'

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. `(x.b.hour_time ?? DateTime.MinValue).TimeOfDay`

Comment: Thank you for replying my question. But it return error. ---

'Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.","ExceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",

Comment: In that case I'll vote to re-open but you ought to edit your question to mention this new error as well. :)

Comment: Side note: it would be far easier to just run that operation client side (not in SQL)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression does not seem to work, since the members `GetValueOrDefault` and `TimeOfDay` are not available for EF DB query translation, therefor you'll somehow have to work around the issue somehow. At the moment I'm not able to verify, but I think the following should be possible

```cs
var find_date = bdb.tbl_store
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.start_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.a.end_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Where(x => x.a.a.store_id == store_id )
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new {
            x.a.a.store_id,
            start_hour_time = x.a.b.hour_time,
            end_hour_time = x.b.hour_time,
            start_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date + x.a.b.hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay,
            end_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date + x.b.hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay
    }).ToList();
```

This way, your query is run when calling `ToList` and everything else (the Lambda expression passed to `Select`) is executed as plain C# on the client, hence there's really no reason for Entity to complain. Admittedly, I do not know for sure, whether these objects are fully resolved when calling `ToList`. If it's not the case, you could do something like this

```cs
var find_date = bdb.tbl_store
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.start_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Join(bdb.tbl_hour, a => a.a.end_hour_id, b => b.hour_id, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Where(x => x.a.a.store_id == store_id)
        .Select(x => new {
            x.a.a.store_id,
            start_hour_time = x.a.b.hour_time,
            end_hour_time = x.b.hour_time 
        })
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new {
            store_id,
            start_hour_time,
            end_hour_time,
            start_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date + start_hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay,
            end_newdatetime = todaysdate.Date + end_hour_time.GetValueOrDefault().TimeOfDay
        }).ToList();
```